# How to stop celery password from being dumped in the log file which is getting dumped via celery url?

Tags: celery, celery-task

I define the celery url in a standard way which has the username as well as password in it. When celerey connects to the database using the celery url it prints the password in the log file because the debug level is set to info. the password is printed from connection.py file in celery which has the info() to print the c_uri.

What do I do, apart from setting the debug level to warn to stop celery from being able to print the password in the log file ? Is there a way to optimize the celery url not to use the password and we can set the password in some other way ?

Comment: are you using Redis as the task broker or as the result backend (or both)?

Comment: Have you already tried updating the logging dictionary?

Comment: No...let me google for the logging dictionary